# eulerian-magnification tuple index out of range python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I'm making an attempt to build and work with this video project in Python.

https://github.com/brycedrennan/eulerian-magnification

The command that I'm trying to run is:

```
eulerian_magnification('media/face.mp4', image_processing='gaussian', freq_min=50.0 / 60.0, freq_max=1.0, amplification=50, pyramid_levels=4)
```

I get back the error:

```
Loading media/face.mp4
Applying bandpass between 0.833333333333 and 1.0 Hz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "eulerian_magnify.py", line 19, in eulerian_magnification
vid_data = temporal_bandpass_filter(vid_data, fps, freq_min=freq_min, freq_max=freq_max)
File "eulerian_magnify.py", line 60, in temporal_bandpass_filter
fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(data, axis=axis)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py", line 225, in fft
n = tmp.shape[axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I installed openCV and SciPy in order to get the program to run but after searching around I haven't been able to solve this issue.

Does anyone know what I can play around with to cure this?

Answer (score 1):

This may indicate that the OpenCV bin directory is not in the path.